# Pro Evolution Soccer 2012 displays error on a NVIDIA on toshiba satelite L755-S5217

Tags: windows-7

Wwhen i try to open my PES 2012 it will display an error message that says:

> Warning :Your computer does not meet the Minimum System Requirements to run this software.As a result, you may experience
>   errors during operation.Your Video Card does not meet the required
>   specification

.(GPU:VRAM 128MB) on my toshiba satelite L7555-S5217

Answer (score 1):

The minimum requirement of pes-2012 is not fulfill,
Confirm your pc configuration.
Pro Evolution Soccer 2012 System Requirements
INTEL CPU -Pentium 4 3.40GHz

AMD CPU -Athlon 64 3400+

Nvidia GPU -GeForce 405

AMD GPU -Radeon HD 3650

RAM -512 MB

OS -Win Xp 32
Direct X   -DX 9
HDD Space - 8 GB

Make sure you do have all the requirements and try playing.  It definitely gonna work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error is correct: Your system is not compatible or able to run the game you want to play. The reason being is likely the graphics card, or lack of. That laptop model only has Intel Integrated Graphics, which are not meant for video games at all.

You may be able to play, but performance will be low and the graphics may be ugly. It may not even work at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try updating Intel graphics drivers:
http://www.intel.com/support/detect.htm?iid=dc_iduu
As intel video cards use any amount of RAM when asked.
Even if you trick the game into running it might still be fairly sluggish, because Intel HD card just plays HD video, as opposed to earlier cards which did not even get close....